# asp.net core2 routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm testing with .net core2 and have following `routes` in my `StatrtUp`'s `configure` method:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "pagination",
            template: "Products/Page{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Product}/{action=List}/{id?}");
});
```

the code is from `Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 6th Edition` Chapter 8, and the book is for Asp.net Core1.

Url `http://localhost:65000/` works great, but `http://localhost:65000/Products/Page2` does not works.

the url `http://localhost:65000/` is calling `ProductController`'s `List` action, but `http://localhost:65000/Products/Page2` gives me this exception:

`InvalidOperationException: The view 'List' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/List.cshtml`

obviously, `/Views/Product/` folder is not searched for `List`. what is the problem with my route? the template for new project i'm using is `Web Application(Model-View-Controller)` with Authentication : `Individula User Accounts`

**Edit**

Added Controller code, this is just sample code from book i mentioned earlier.

```
public class ProductController : Controller {

    private IProductRepository repository;
    int PageSize = 4;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository repo) {
        repository = repo;
    }


    public ViewResult List(int page = 1) => View(
        new ProductsListViewModel {
            Products = repository.Products
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                .Skip(PageSize * (page - 1))
                .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your Product Controller?

Comment: It is very simple. and I'm editing post to add it.

Comment: Your view file is at /Views/Product/List.cshtml? Does the case match?

Comment: Yes, but i'm on windows, and there, we don't need case match.

Comment: Fair enough. If you’re hitting the Action method then your routing is not the problem. Something in the project settings or the Program.cs/Startup.cs

Comment: @DanSoper see the answer, i found the solution (and/or problem) in github. nothing was wrong!

Comment: An excellent find!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was a bug in Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.1 and updating it to 2.0.3 fixed the bug. It was related to new Razor Pages feature in asp.net core 2 and using Page in route template.

See this link for more resolution [GitHub aspnet/Mvc Issue 6660](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6660)